# WC Fields Factory: Using entries from product page in cart functions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

With Woocommerce, I'm using WC Fields Factory plugin to capture information in the product page prior to it being added to the cart. I need to access the data that's entered in order to perform calculations in my child theme functions file and show the right information in the cart, but haven't been able to find out how to do it. I can however confirm that the data entered on the product page is being added to the order confirmation email/order details screens correctly.

Based on *"[Custom cart item weight in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401178/custom-cart-item-weight-in-woocommerce/53401994#53401994)"* answer code, here is my complete modified code version:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_weight_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
function add_weight_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
    // For product variations handling
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    // Get an instance of the product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // The default product weight and dimensions
    $cart_item_data['weight']['default'] = $product->get_weight() ?: '0'; // Change this to use weight entered on product page (new field)
    $cart_item_data['length']['default'] = $product->get_length() ?: '0'; // Change this to use length entered on product page (new field)
    $cart_item_data['width']['default'] = $product->get_width() ?: '0';   // Change this to use width entered on product page (new field)
    $cart_item_data['height']['default'] = $product->get_height() ?: '0'; // Change this to use height entered on product page (new field)
    //___________________ Also add another field 'carton_qty' from the page to use in the below calculations instead of 2

    ## ====> HERE YOU CAN MAKE YOUR WEIGHT CALCULATIONS <==== ##
    $new_weight_value = (($cart_item_data['length']['default'] * $cart_item_data['width']['default'] * $cart_item_data['height']['default']) / 5000);
    $old_total_weight = ($cart_item_data['weight']['default'] * 2);
    $new_total_weight = ($new_weight_value * 2);

    // Set the new calculated weights
    $cart_item_data['weight']['new'] = $new_weight_value;
    $cart_item_data['weight']['totalold'] = $old_total_weight;
    $cart_item_data['weight']['totalnew'] = $new_total_weight;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_item_weight', 10, 2 );
function display_cart_item_weight( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset($cart_item['weight']) ) {
        // Display original weight
        if ( isset($cart_item['weight']['default']) ) {
            $item_data[] = array(
                'key'       => __('Carton Weight (std)', 'woocommerce'),
                'value'     => wc_format_weight( $cart_item['weight']['default'] ),
            );
        }

        // Display calculated weight
        if ( isset($cart_item['weight']['new']) ) {
            $item_data[] = array(
                'key'     => __( 'Carton Weight (vol)', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'   => wc_format_weight( $cart_item['weight']['new'] ),
            );      
        }

        // Display calculated original total weight
        if ( isset($cart_item['weight']['totalold']) ) {
            $item_data[] = array(
                'key'     => __( 'Line Weight (std)', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'   => wc_format_weight( $cart_item['weight']['totalold'] ),
            );      
        }
        // Display calculated total weight

        if ( isset($cart_item['weight']['totalnew']) ) {
            $item_data[] = array(
                'key'     => __( 'Line Weight (vol)', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'   => wc_format_weight( $cart_item['weight']['totalnew'] ),
            );
            if ($cart_item['weight']['totalold'] < $cart_item['weight']['totalnew']){
                echo "<span style='color:#515151;font-size:1.6em;'><b>&nbsp;&#9951;</b></span>";
            }               
        }
    }
    return $item_data;
}

// Set the new weight in cart items
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_cart_item_weight', 25, 1 );
function set_custom_cart_item_weight( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if ( isset($cart_item['weight']['new']) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_weight(max ($cart_item['weight']['totalold'], $cart_item['weight']['totalnew']));
        }
    }
}
```

I only need the below 'default product weight and dimensions' section to use the details submitted by the user instead of the stored product details, the rest of the function is pasted above for context:

```
// The default product weight and dimensions
        $cart_item_data['weight']['default'] = $product->get_weight() ?: '0'; // Change this to use weight entered on product page (new field)
        $cart_item_data['length']['default'] = $product->get_length() ?: '0'; // Change this to use length entered on product page (new field)
        $cart_item_data['width']['default'] = $product->get_width() ?: '0';   // Change this to use width entered on product page (new field)
        $cart_item_data['height']['default'] = $product->get_height() ?: '0'; // Change this to use height entered on product page (new field)
        //___________________ Also add another field 'carton_qty' from the page to use in the below calculations instead of 2
```

One example, the weight shows on the front end of WC Field Factory as field name 'carton_weight'. I've tried all sorts of things including getting order meta. I found some code in the plugin files that indicates I should use `$value=["wccpf_carton_weight_1"]` etc. but nothing I've tried has worked.

I'm using WC Fields Factory version 3.0.3 (current version).

Comment: I think that with WC Fields Factory plugin are alreay using the same hooks, so you try to set a higher interger value for the hook priorities, trying for example to replace the priority `10` to `5000` for example (priority is located inside the `add_action()` or `add_filter()` as the third argument).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks (I didn't know about priority) - I changed that and again tried various names but it always seems to return nothing. As soon as I change the `$product->get_weight()` to anything else I get "Carton Weight (std):
N/A"

Comment: For customizations like this, you should better use hand coded custom fields instead, as with WC Fields Factory, every time people get stuck on this kind of requirements.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I agree, but I didn't know how to do that at all so I had to use a plugin and got most of the way there lol :) I appreciate the advice though, thank you.

Comment: There is many examples in stackOverFlow (and on the web) on how to add custom fields on Woocommerce products

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this topic for hours... I finally understood how WCFieldsFactory works, after reading source code:
https://github.com/wp-plugins/wc-fields-factory/blob/master/classes/product-form.php

If you want to access custom field value **BEFORE** product is added to your cart, it is quite easy: juste call `$_REQUEST['field_key']`,
where field_key can be found on WCFieldsFactory user interface when setting field parameters. <= Tested, it works.

If you want to access **AFTER** product addition to cart (ie, during checkout for example), you can do it through `cart_item_data['wccpf_'.field_key]` <= Not tested yet, but should work according to source code.

Hope this helps, even 3 years later...